# Strange has_many Association Behavior in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, models

I've got two tables, `User` and `Allergy`. These are connected via another table, `UserAllergy`. The models are as would be expected:

```rb
class User
  has_many :user_allergies
  has_many :allergies, through: :user_allergies
end

class UserAllergy
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :allergy
end

class Allergy
  has_many :user_allergies
  has_many :users, through :user_allergies
end
```

What I'm confused about is creating allergies from a multiple-valued `collection_select` in my `User` form.

I have the following field:

```rb
<%= f.collection_select :allergy_ids, 
                        Allergy.all, 
                        :id, 
                        :name, 
                        {}, 
                        { class: 'form-control', multiple: true }
%>
```

This correctly inserts a key into my params like so if I selected the `Allergies` with ids 1 and 2:

```rb
{ user: { id: "1", allergy_ids: ["", "1", "2"] } }
```

When I create the user instantiated with `@user = User.new( my_params )`, the weird behavior occurs. Instead of inserting the provided `allergy_ids` into the join table, Rails does a query to get all current `user_allergies` for the user, then deletes all of the current `user_allergies`:

```rb
Started PATCH "/employees/regular_user" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-18 22:08:30 -0400
Processing by UsersController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{ "allergy_ids"=>["", "1", "2", "3"]}, "button"=>"", "id"=>"regular_user"}
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Allergy Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "allergies".* FROM "allergies" INNER JOIN "user_allergies" ON "allergies"."id" = "user_allergies"."allergy_id" WHERE "user_allergies"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
  SQL (0.1ms)  DELETE FROM "user_allergies" WHERE "user_allergies"."user_id" = ? AND "user_allergies"."allergy_id" = 1  [["user_id", 1]]
   (27.4ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/employees/regular_user
Completed 302 Found in 32ms (ActiveRecord: 27.8ms)
```

Anyone knows what gives, or what I need to do to create allergies implicitly? I've tried `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and changing around the form to use `fields_for`.

Comment: I've done this in a similar situation (assigning students to classes in a school setting), and yes, the assignment is a wholesale replacement of the class list. In your example above, it's deleting existing UserAllergies, is it also adding the new ones in? Or is the User left with no UserAllergies?

Comment: It only deletes the old ones, leaving a user with no allergies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I went and looked at code of mine that does a similar function. Here's what my create method looks like. This is creating a Student with assignment to Student Groups in a school setting (I didn't use "class" since Ruby wouldn't like that).

```
def create
  @student = Student.new(student_params)

  if @student.save
    @student.student_groups = StudentGroup.where(id: params[:student][:student_group_ids])
    flash[:success] = "Student was successfully created."
    redirect_to @student
  else
    render 'new', notice: "Your student could not be created."
  end
end
```

I completely ignore the Student Group IDs when creating the student_params, since I'm not using them for mass assignment.

Yes, one extra line of code. I'd be really interested to hear if there's a way to accomplish this via mass assignment.

Comment: I'll just use this approach to get this task done because I'm tired of trying to get the mass-assignment to work.

If anyone else comes along with an answer that's more of Rails' magic, then I'll gladly accept their answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing one part of the puzzle which is the relation from Allergy to User.

```
class Allergy
  has_many :user_allergies
  has_many :users, through: :user_allergies
end
```

Comment: Yeah, I attempted to add the association to make sure that wasn't it, and it didn't resolve the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Just give the following code a try-

```
params.require(:user).permit(___, ____, {allergy_ids: []}, ____, ____)
```